# jenkins global variable not able to updated in same job

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have written a groovy script which is able to update global variable value.

```
instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
globalNodeProperties = instance.getGlobalNodeProperties()
envVarsNodePropertyList = globalNodeProperties.getAll(hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class)
env = envVarsNodePropertyList.get(0).getEnvVars()
def x=env.get("Suite_execution_no").toInteger()
println(x+1)
x=x+1
env.put("Suite_execution_no",x.toString())
def date = new Date()
env.put("Suite_start_time",date.toString())
```

I am running this script during prepare environment for build and this global variable get successfully get updated but problem in the same job when i am fetching same global variable it is giving me old value. Any solution do you have please post